# Why does Range.FindNext NOT inherit parameters?

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have a project which requires a lot of searches to be done through various sheets, for which I use VBA's `Find` function together with `FindNext` in a `Do While...Loop`. It has come to my attention that the FindNext function does not inherit the parameters provided by the previous search.

Thus, if I were to declare `MatchCase:=True`, the FindNext function may find a value which does not match the search string.

For example, this is what I would do (including an alternative to FindNext)

```
    Set FindComp = wbc.Range("B2:B" & LRow).Find(splititm(0), MatchCase:=True)
    If Not FindComp Is Nothing Then FRow = FindComp.Row

    Do While Not FindComp Is Nothing
        If wbc.Cells(FindComp.Row, "J").Value = wbc.Cells(cell.Row, "J").Value And wbc.Cells(FindComp.Row, cell.Column).Value <> "" Then
            wbc.Cells(FindComp.Row, cell.Column).Value = ""
        End If

        'Does not inherit arguments
        Set FindComp = wbc.Range("B2:B" & LRow).FindNext(FindComp) 

        'Working alternative
        Set FindComp = wbc.Range("B2:B" & LRow).Find(splititm(0), after:=FindComp, MatchCase:=True)

        If FindComp.Row = FRow Then Exit Do
    Loop
```

Why is it that FindNext does not inherit these parameters? Is my code/train of thought faulty?

Comment: It works just fine for me

Comment: I don't have it specified. It does not find the search string as a substring either, as it just finds a largely different value. E.g. search string `89.0700.011.0005`, but it finds `89.2360.015.0001`

Comment: I think you are confusing between Match Case and SearchFormat? MatchCase is for strings....  differentiating between capital and lower-case letters... `MatchCase (Optional Variant): True to make the search case sensitive. The default value is False.`

Comment: Right, so technically a wrong use of parameters there. Still, it does work in getting the right cell. Does not explain why FindNext is giving wrong ranges

Comment: Like I mentioned, it works for me. If i search for `89.0700.011.0005`, it gives me only that and not `89.2360.015.0001`

Comment: I used [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) code for testing

Comment: Very odd, almost has me thinking this is rather a system issue. I recall reading a thread by someone experiencing the same issue. FindNext didn't inherit any arguments either. SearchFormat is not what I need, simply need xlWhole.

Comment: Can you try the code from the link that I shared... Use it as it is shown there... Do you still see unnecessary results?

Comment: There are 8 pieces of code there of which the "final" one does not use FindNext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189066/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-tim-stack).

Comment: `Section 3 – .FindNext` in the one that I am referring to... Possible to join me in the chat. Link mentioned in previous comment